# locale.h options for spanish for C

Tags: c, locale

I'm trying to use the spanish options of LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME OR LC_MONETARY for spanish language.
I can use special characters with: setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "spanish"), but the other options doesn't work, and the option "es_ES" doesn't work neither.
I searched internet for an answer but I didn't find anything so, maybe someone in this place could tell me about this issue.
Thanx in advance to anybody answering with a clue.
My IDE for C is Code::Blocks 17, and my laptop run windows 10.

Comment: You *have* tried https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings did you?

Comment: Yes, but there is not a detailed syntax about how to set, for example, thousands separator, decimal or time for a specific language, wich is spanish in my case. Thanx.

Comment: For example I tryied to use setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "spanish"); but it doesn' display the thousands separator.

Comment: "spanish" is probably not what you want. Higher chance for success might have "es-ES" or "es-ES.UTF-8" (although Windows is almost completely UTF-16 now, you may try that instead)

Comment: Thanx, but it doesn't work the way you tell me. For the option LC_CTYPE it work just with "spanish", for the special characters, but for the rest of options, like thousands sep, and the other neither one.